# React: trying to add an onClick to a li tag but the click handler function is undefined

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react, so I don't know much about it.
I am trying to add a click handler to a li but the function seems to be undefined?

```
var ActivityList = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {name:"test"};
  },
  handleClick:function(e){
    console.log(e.target.name);
  },
  render:function(){
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.props.data.map(function(game){
         return <li onClick={this.handleClick} name={game.name}>{game.name}</li>;
        })
      }
      </ul>);
  }
});
```

I am wondering if it is because i have my scoping wrong here?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Set `this` to [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), because in [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) callback `this` refers to global scope(in browser it is `window` or `undefined` if you use [`strict mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode))

```
this.props.data.map(function(game) {
  return <li onClick={this.handleClick} name={game.name}>{game.name}</li>;
}, this);
  ^^^^^
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/29552/)

Comment: Thanks a  lot, Life saver :)

Answer (score 5):

You can also use an arrow function to avoid binding `this` in the function at all:

```
this.props.data.map(game =>
    <li onClick={this.handleClick} name={game.name}>{game.name}</li>
)
```