# ReactJs: target.key undefined after method is reached from li rendered by map function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, reactjs

I'm currently trying to coding a react app that would do the following:
- Create a list of questions from an array using a map function.
- Making each list element clickable using a onClick prop
- The linked onClick method changes the state in another file with my 'qsChange' prop.

I had a hard time making my list clickable and finally managed following this question: [React: trying to add an onClick to a li tag but the click handler function is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35117485/react-trying-to-add-an-onclick-to-a-li-tag-but-the-click-handler-function-is-un)

However, now I cannot make it so that my variable 'choice' returns a defined value. I would want var choice to be equal to "A ?", "B ?" or "C ?" depending on which

I click.

Here's my code:

```
var questions = ["A ?", "B ?", "C ?"];
var Questions = React.createClass({
    handleClick: function() {
      var visibility;
      if(this.props.visibility) {
          document.getElementById('second').style.display = 'none';
          visibility = false;
          this.props.onChange(visibility);
      } else {
          document.getElementById('second').style.display = 'block';
          visibility = true;
          this.props.onChange(visibility);
      }
    },

/* Here is where my problem lies */
    onItemClick: function(e){
        var choice = e.target.key;
        this.props.qsChange(choice);
        alert(choice);
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="bigqs">
                <div id="first" className="small" style={firstStyle}>
                     <h1>Question :</h1>
                         <button style={btnStyle} onClick={this.handleClick}>
                                <img id="arrow" src="../../img/arrow.png" />
                         </button>
                     <h3 id="selectedQuestion">{this.props.selected}</h3>
                </div>
                <div id="second" className="small" style={{display: 'none'}}>
                   <h4>
                      <ul>
                           {questions.map(function(qs, i) {return <li key={qs[i]} onClick={this.onItemClick}>{qs}</li>;}, this)}
                      </ul>
                   </h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
     }
});
```

I am still a newbie, so please be indulgent ;-)
I hope I was clear enough.

Ps: I have also tried this guide but it didn't work for me: http://derpturkey.com/react-pass-value-with-onclick/

Comment: don't bother with getting the key, just pass the question as another argument `onClick={event => this.onItemClick(event, qs)}`

Comment: @azium : I don't know what syntax I should use inside the onItemClick if  I do that. Could you help me out?

Comment: added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of grabbing the question from `target`, you can pass question through to your handler. Also, since inside map `qs` is a string, `qs[i]` will be getting the character in the string from that index. You just need to make sure your `key` is unique.

```
onItemClick: function(choice) {
  this.props.qsChange(choice)
  alert(choice)
},

render() {
  return (
   <div>
     ...
     {questions.map(qs =>
       <li key={qs} onClick={() => this.onItemClick(qs)}>{qs}</li>
     )}
     ...
   </div>
  )
}
```

In fact, your intermediate function isn't doing much, you can just call your props function inside render:

```
render() {
  return (
   <div>
     ...
     {questions.map(qs =>
       <li key={qs} onClick={() => this.props.qsChange(qs)}>{qs}</li>
     )}
     ...
   </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that did it !